Adding a Katz-Lindell Tag or Book-Question Tag or None
As many of you already know, questions from the book of Katz-Lindell, Introduction to Modern Cryptography, asked many times in our site.
I want to create a tag for these questions as tag:Katz-Lindell to unite them. I've searched one to find since I remember that I've seen it. With the tag, the dupe search may become easier.
Or should we create a general tag:book-question?
What is your opinion?

Existing tags
If you look at all of the existing tags, they pretty much each represent a single, objectively definable concept that appears in the subject of cryptography itself. Katz-Lindell is not an algorithm, protocol, etc, but the name of a book (or rather the authors names). 
It would be a clear outlier when examined alongside the other tags.
Meta tags
This may qualify as a "meta tag", which are generally discouraged.
In the post "The death of Meta Tags", the following conclusion appears:

If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question...

It fails the meta tag test
It fails the test provided in the quote above. You can't define the content of a question with a single Katz-Lindell tag, but you can do so with a PRG tag (or similar).
This same argument applies for the generalized form of a book tag.
Bottom line
I think it's not a good fit.

That meta tag conclusion is very nice.
